# Redis values set from Python are not reflecting in redis client

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis, redis-server

I have installed `redis` on my OS X, and trying to set and get some values in Redis from Python 3.5 client. I have the Redis server on (through command `redis-server`) and the redis-client on as well (opened through the command `redis-cli`). This is what I am trying on Python:

```
import redis
r = redis.StrictRedis()
r.set("foo", "bar")
r.get("foo")
```

This prints `bar` as expected. However, if I go to my redis-client prompt and try `get foo`, it returns `nil`. In the same way, if I set a value in the redis-client itself, like `set boo too`, calling `get boo` in the client returns `too` as expected, however, in my Python client if I run `r.get(boo)`, I get `None`.

Funny thing is, they are synced between their own instances. So if I open another Python command prompt and type `r.get("foo")`, it returns `bar`. In the same way, if I open another `redis-cli` instance and type `get boo`, I get `too`. It is only that the values between Python client and Redis client are not syncing. I even tried to enforce a `bgsave` from Python client after setting the value there, and it did trigger a save in the window where `redis-server` is running, but the values do not reflect in the `redis-cli` window even after that.

They were working perfectly fine until some days back, this has started happening sometime recently.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You are obviously not connecting to the same redis-server from the clis and python code...

Comment: I guessed as much, but cannot understand how to connect both to the same instance, and why did this start to happen suddenly!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are accessing (setting/getting values) through different `db`s in your `redis-cli` and your `redis-py` instance. `redis` servers can have multiple key-value stores (or "tables") completely isolated from one another. These are referred throughout the documentation as `db`, and are uniquely identified by integers.

If you are instancing `redis-py` exactly as in your code snippet, with:

```
import redis
r = redis.StrictRedis()
```

Then you are using the constructor's default value for db, which is **0**. ([See documentation](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#redis.Redis))

If the values differ between the Python implementation and `redis-cli`, then most likely your command line client is running on a different `db`than 0. You can check which `db` you are working on with the command [CLIENT LIST](https://redis.io/commands/client-list), which will return your current database id.

To switch to the same database as the Python implementation, just run on your `redis-cli`:

```
SELECT 0
```

([See documentation](https://redis.io/commands/select))

Or, alternatively, you can call your `redis-py` constructor with the desired `db` parameter:

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(db=3) # 3 is an example value for your redis-cli's working db
```

Comment: Thanks. I instantiated it with `db` value as 3 in Python, and set it to so in Redis as well: `SELECT 3`. Output:

    `127.0.0.1:6379[3]> get foo
    (nil)`

Comment: @SexyBeast your `redis-py` database value was definitely set to 0, whereas you don't know which database your `redis-cli` was using, so you can't expect to be able to _get_ the same value with 100% certainty. Try running `SELECT 0` and then `GET foo` in your `redis-cli`

Comment: That's what I said, I tried setting it to 3 in both, then ran the commands. Still not reflecting..

Comment: @SexyBeast but did you also run `SET foo bar` (in any one of the clients) after setting both databases to 3?

Comment: Yes. Did that. And still not reflecting! :(

Comment: Please try FastoRedis, it will be more simple to find issue which you have.